# geolocation in web view of android is getting only once

Tags: android, android-webview

I have to retrieve a user's location in a WebView of android app,I used this code:

```
 WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
    webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(MainActivity.this.getFilesDir().getPath());
```

and I called webViewClient and webChromeClient like this:

```
     mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
     mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new UriWebChromeClient());
```

my  UriWebChromeClient.class is as follows:

```
private class UriWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
                                  boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
        mWebviewPop = new WebView(mContext);
        mWebviewPop.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebviewPop.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebviewPop.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);

       /* mWebviewPop.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(getFilesDir().getPath());*/


        mWebviewPop.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mContainer.addView(mWebviewPop);
        WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
        transport.setWebView(mWebviewPop);
        resultMsg.sendToTarget();

        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(final String origin,
                                                   final GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        // Always grant permission since the app itself requires location
        // permission and the user has therefore already granted it
        Log.d("Geo_location", ""+origin);


        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
        Log.d("onCloseWindow", "called");
    }

}
```

and I declared the following permissions in manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
```

atlast  it access the current location but only at  first  time, from second time onwards its not getting current location.

I had searched a lot,still not found exact solution , any suggestion will be greately appreciated....

Comment: did you solved it?